# Android mapview geopoint difference emulator and device

Tags: android, geolocation, android-mapview, geopoints

i am getting data from gps provider using mylocation class. code is this:

```
MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult() {
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            //Got the location!

            // for phone
            //currentLocation = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1000000),
            //   (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1000000));

            // for emulator
            currentLocation = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude()),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude()));

            doSomething();

        }
    };
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

when i use the app in emulator(2.3.3) it shows the correct location without multiplying anything.

but when i use it in a device(4.0) lat and lon need to multiplied with 1000000. i couldn't find why. i don't think its because of the version of android. anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the MapView uses microdegress for its units so you need to multiply by 1e6.  Otherwise you show up off the coast of Africa - basically lat long of approximately 0,0

From the documentation on GeoPoint:

> An immutable class representing a pair of latitude and longitude, stored as integer numbers of microdegrees.

Don't know why the emulator is working - it shouldn't.

Comment: i tried as you said but it is not working in emulator. if there is no problem for devices, if it is only working wrong on emulator it's fine for me. is there any possibility for this to behave different in each device? for android 2.3 and 4.0 for example??